# Keyboard Mouse Method

Tags: windows-7, mouse-click, double-click

My mouse is broken.

How do I use the keyboard mouse method to click the 'minimize/maximize/close' icon on a window or double-click to open a file,the same way I use the left-click on a mouse to minimize/maximize/close or double-click to open?

I can move the cursor to the 'minimize/maximize/close' icon but cannot click on it to execute that instruction.I know the standard keyboard shortcuts to minimize/maximize/close but I'm looking for the keyboard mouse method specifically.

I've googled but unable to find any answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *Mouse Keys* feature to emulate mouse movement with numpad.

To enable *Mouse Keys*, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left Shift</kbd>+<kbd>NumLock</kbd>. A confirmation dialog will appear, confirm it with <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

How to emulate mouse with *Mouse Keys*: (courtesy of [Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/use-mouse-keys-to-move-the-mouse-pointer))

- Numpad keys

  <kbd>7</kbd>, <kbd>8</kbd>, <kbd>9</kbd>,
  <kbd>4</kbd>, ....... <kbd>6</kbd>,
  <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd>

  move the mouse pointer in the direction the key is pointing, relatively to <kbd>5</kbd>. For example <kbd>7</kbd> moves the pointer up and to the left and <kbd>6</kbd> moves it right.
- <kbd>5</kbd> presses *selected* mouse button, <kbd>+</kbd> double-clicks with *selected* mouse button
- *Selected* mouse button can be chosen with <kbd>/</kbd>, <kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>*</kbd>

  - <kbd>/</kbd> selects left button
  - <kbd>-</kbd> selects right button
  - <kbd>*</kbd> selects both buttons
- <kbd>0</kbd> starts dragging with *selected* mouse button, <kbd>.</kbd> releases the key and stops dragging

Comment: Thanks,the /and+ combination on the numpad keys does exactly what I wanted.Great!